# what is endpoint in image processing?

Tags: image-processing, matlab

what is endpoint? I have a sample code to [detect endpoints](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/4251/versions/1/download/zip/find_skel_ends.zip) . it finds endpoint with sample, but when i run for my sample tif image, it does not well. so I want know the exactly meaning of endpoint in image processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This concept is related to the [topological skeletonization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton) of an object in shape analysis. It produces a thin sert of lines equidistant to the boundaries, preserving  geometrical and topological properties of the object. Some use the term [medial axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis). Some points possess a specific interest: branch or junction points (where sereval lines meet, i.e. a point with more than two neighbors) and termination, terminating or end points (a point with less than two neighbors), located at extremities.